# DNS resolution with using multiple name servers fails patriotically

Tags: dns

I am using centos 7 machine , and i need to be able to resolve aws and on on-premises dns records

so my resolv.conf is looks similar to the one below : (changed the actual ip's)

```
search adomain1.com domain2.com
options rotate timeout:2 attempts:40
#name server for domain1
nameserver 169.1.1.252
#name servers for domain2
nameserver 23.44.22.1
nameserver 23.44.22.2
nameserver 23.44.22.1
```

issue description:

when i trying to ping a machine in domain1  i am getting ping respond but
if i am trying to ping for the second time i am getting :
ping: machine1.domain1: Name or service not known

i am getting the same results when i am pinging the other domain machine

Answer (score 1):

> `#name server for domain1`

That's not how name servers in resolv.conf work. The resolver *only* switches to a different address if the original server *does not respond at all.*

But if the first server actually responds with "No such domain", that is considered a successful query and does not cause a retry. This means that all servers must provide the same content.

The built-in Linux DNS resolver does not support per-domain nameservers – it needs another, full resolver to do the job. For example, you should install Unbound, Dnsmasq, or even BIND 9.